# For general use - MS Excel dot plot with error bars

Tags: excel, plot, graph, dot

I am making this graph with information I have collated for the use of other doctors. It took me about 3-4 days to collect this information.

This will be very useful, since a simple to use graph containing all this information is missing. I will make this generally available on the net.

This is a sheet of congenital malformations caused by antiseizure medications.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTzOkwB2PtSlAU0ldO-h2D2dqqflkXq58SWK2eOXa2V8BVpjjqAAQp2Wh6NP9L1yg/pub?output=csv

1. There are 25 antiseizure medications in rows. The names of the antiepileptics are noted in the first column.
2. There are 6 sources (USA, Europe, Australia, UK, India and case series). The names of these sources are noted in the first row.
3. For each source, the first column is the total number of pregnancies, and the second column is the total number of congenital malformations within that group of pregnancies. The rest of the columns are calculated values for proportion and error bars.

I am trying to make a graph like this:
https://toptipbio.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Example-forest-plot-in-Excel.jpg

(I tried using the instructions on this website, but cant get it to work - and I cant figure out how to include data from all 6 sites and the total).

I want a graph with:

1. Antiepileptic names on the y-axis
2. For each antiepileptic - plot dot plots congenital malformation percentage, with 95% error bars on the x-axis. Plot data from all 6 sources, plus an additional plot with the total pregnancies and total malformations from all sources below the 6 sources.
3. For the x-axis labels, use short forms (USA, Eur, Aus, UK, Ind and series)
4. For each dot plot, note the total number of pregnancies in brackets beside the x-axis label.